# Validate Json Schema Draft V4

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a Json schema as below , when i validate it on a online validatior like http://jsonschemalint.com/draft4/# it says its valid.I changed "type" to  "object" , "array" , "string" and kept the rest of the structure same .still it says valid schema. My understanding was when 
type=object there should be "properties" 
when type=array there should be"items"

```
{
  "title": "Example Schema",
  "type": "string",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "firstName",
    "lastName"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the docs](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor8):

> Some validation keywords only apply to one or more primitive types.
>   When the primitive type of the instance cannot be validated by a given
>   keyword, validation for this keyword and instance SHOULD succeed.

So the behavior you mention is correct.

Comment: To expand on this answer...
All of these keywords have default values if they are not present.  For example, if validating an object that doesn't have a `properties` keyword, it is considered present with a value of `{}`.